# How should I say: When we talk, it sounds like we are singing

Tags: grammar

Because I am half-Swedish, I usually joke about this to other people. But now, I don't really know how to say it in Japanese!

Maybe...

> 話すのとき、歌のように聞こえる。。。

Comment: To compare two things, the two things should always be expressed with the same part of speech. 「話す」 is a verb and 「歌」 is a noun.  Not a good combo.

Answer (score 4):

It would LITERALLY translate to

> (私たちが)話すとき/話すと、歌っているように(orみたいに)聞こえる(or聞こえます)。
>   When we talk, it sounds like we are singing.

But to sound more natural I think you can say

> スウェーデン語で話すと、歌ってるみたいに聞こえるよ/聞こえますよ。
>   (Lit. When I speak Swedish, I sound like singing)
>   スウェーデン語って、歌ってるみたいに聞こえるんだよ/聞こえるんですよ。
>   (Lit. Swedish language sounds like you're singing)
>   スウェーデン語って、歌みたいだよ/ですよ。/ 歌みたいに聞こえるよ/聞こえますよ。
>   (Lit. Swedish language is like a song / sounds like a song)
>   etc...

Answer (score -2):

Not a bad start, but this might be a little closer:

> 話す時、歌う気がしている。

時【とき】 can be affixed directly to plain verbs.

Comment: Could anyone explain why this sounds wrong?